# Is Storing Duplicate Data Good Practice in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore as my database and have not designed databases much in general.

At the moment I have a collection of 'products', where each document is a 'product'.

I would like to store a subset of the data in the 'product' document, in my 'user profile' document for speed and to limit the number of queries to the database.

I was wondering if this was good practice and if not, what is the better practice?

Thanks.

Comment: Data duplication in nosql databases is common.  Whether or not it's "good" in your case is up to you to decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Doug commented, it is quite common to duplicate data in NoSQL databases. In fact, this is often why these databases scale to such massive read workloads: those implementations do more work when writing, so that they have less work to do to read the data.

If you're new to the topic, I highly recommend:

- Reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- Watching [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video)